# Read CurrentDate in Regular Expression or Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

We have an XML file that has  the below structure:

```
<DocumentDate> 2019 </DocumentDate>
<Order>
  <name> Value of year - 2019 </name>
  <value> 1200 </value>

  <name> Value of year - 2018 </name>
  <value> 13400 </value>

  <name> Value of year - 2017 </name>
  <value> 2300 </value>
</Order>
```

I need to read these "Value of each year" and related "value"

In our XML we have just the last three years data and XML is updating each year.

I am looking for a way to do it just one time so I am searching for a way to say :

```
    name = "Value of year" - + DocumentDate
    name2= "Value of year" - + DocumentDate-1
    name3 = "Value of year -" + DocumentDate-2
```

my issue is to read DocumentDate as a variable, because I want to use it as I mentioned.
Can anyone suggest me a solution?
I have tried :

```
String DocDate= "/Root/DocumentDate"
```

But it does not give me "2019", it show me the string of **"/Root/DocumentDate"**

P.S. I should read /Root/DocumentDate but also Current date will works for me. Also I am doing this in Java, I need to convert XML to Excel.

Thanks

Comment: If you are converting the xml to xls, then you can use the VBA or macro to get the current date/year rather poking around the logic with xml and java. If you still want to get the year from xml refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the below xpath to get the year as text.

```
//DocumentDate/normalize-space(text())
```

[image]

Comment: Can I save the value in a String? I mean it is not working for me in this way: 
String MyString = "//DocumentDate/normalize-space(text())";

Comment: how you are reading the xml content? when you `String MyString = "//DocumentDate/normalize-space(text())` you are assigning the xpath to the string variable, but we have to execute the xpath on your xml content.

Comment: I tried this way: XPathExpression expr = XPath.compileXPath("/Root/DocumentDate"); But it gives me the error of Type mismatch: cannot convert from XPath to XPathExpression